# Process.Exited not raised when the parent process is waiting

Tags: c#, concurrency

I want to launch a bunch of child processes and then wait for all the processes to be completed before proceeding.  All works fine.  But I want to introduce a delay between starting each consecutive process.  The problem I face is that the Exited event from the child process can happen during the delay and I am not able to receive that event in the parent process while it is asleep.

please advice.

Here is some code:

```
    public void SetupProcess(string program, string args)
    {
        cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = program;
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
        cmd.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        //cmd.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.Exited += new EventHandler(cmd_Exited);
   }

    public bool StartProcess(int delay)
    {
        bool retval = false;
        if (cmd.Start())
        {
            Thread.Sleep(delay);
        }
        return retval;
    }


    private void cmd_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pIsRunning = false;
        if (Exited != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process exited. notfying queue...");
            Exited(this, null); // signal the queue to run the next process
        }
    }
```

Comment: GrawCube,   this is along the lines of what Deadly Bagel suggested but with the delay factor which is the cause of the problem,

Comment: Thats a great idea GrawCube.  Thanks very much!  In the meantime,  I found another solution that I will post.

Answer (score 0):

I took the time to implement GrawCube's suggestion.   The code below will ensure:
1)  No more than MaxConcurrent processes are started at a time (typical, for example no more than 4 processes on a Quad)
2)  There is a certain Delay introduced between starting consecutive process (in my case the messaging service imposed this constraint)

Here is the code, hope that helps:

```
    class ProcessExQueue
    {
        public int MaxConcurrent { get; set; }
        public int Delay { get; set; }
        public Action Done;
        private List<Timer> _timers;

        private List<ProcessEx> Servers = new List<ProcessEx>();
        byte _running = 0;
        private DateTime _lastStart;

        public ProcessExQueue()
        {
            MaxConcurrent = 4;
            Delay = 15000;
            _timers = new List<Timer>();
        }

        public void Add(ProcessEx Server)
        {
            Servers.Add(Server);
            Server.Exited += cmd_Exited;
            Server.Started += cmd_Started;
        }

        public void RunProcessTimer(int delay)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(DoTask);
            timer.Interval = delay;
            timer.AutoReset = false; // only first time
            timer.Start();
            _timers.Add(timer);
            Console.WriteLine("timer started with delay {0} @ {1} ", delay, DateTime.Now);
        }

        void DoTask(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("timer call @ {0}", DateTime.Now);
            lock (this)
            {
                if (Servers.Count > 0 && _running <= MaxConcurrent)
                {
                    ProcessEx ToRun = Servers[0];
                    ToRun.Starter = (Timer)source;
                    Servers.Remove(ToRun);
                    bool success = ToRun.StartProcess();
                    if (success)
                        _running++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("nothing started, queue size {0} running {1}", Servers.Count, _running);
                }
            }
        }

        public void StartFirstProcesses()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Servers.Count; i++)
            {
                RunProcessTimer(i == 0 ? 1000 : Delay*(i));
            }
        }

        private void cmd_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Queue: process exited {0}.", ((ProcessEx)sender).GetPID());

            // find the timer and get rid of it;
            //TODO

            Timer found = _timers.FirstOrDefault(t => t == ((ProcessEx)sender).Starter);
            if (found != null)
            {
                found.Enabled = false;
            }

            lock (this)
            {
                _running--;
            }

            if (Servers.Count == 0) // no more processes to run
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No more processes to run.  some threads may be asleep");
                if (_running == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("disarming all timers");
                    _timers.ForEach(t=> t.Enabled=false);  
                    Done();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Servers.Count > 0 && _running <= MaxConcurrent)
                {
                    TimeSpan tspan = (DateTime.Now - _lastStart);
                    RunProcessTimer(tspan.Milliseconds < Delay?Delay - tspan.Milliseconds:1);
                }
            }
        }

        private void cmd_Started(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Queue: process started {0}", ((ProcessEx)sender).GetPID());
            _lastStart = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    class ProcessEx
    {
        public Timer Starter { get; set; }

        public bool IsRunning
        {
            get
            {
                return pIsRunning;
            }
        }

        private bool pIsRunning = false;

        public delegate void OutputEventHandler(ProcessEx sender, string Output, bool IsError);

        public delegate void StatusEventHandler(ProcessEx sender, EventArgs e);

        public event StatusEventHandler Started;

        public event StatusEventHandler Exited;

        private Process cmd;

        public int GetPID()
        {
            return cmd.Id;
        }

        public bool StartProcess()
        {
            bool retval = false;
            if (cmd.Start())
            {
                pIsRunning = true;
                retval = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Running  {0} {1}", cmd.StartInfo.FileName, cmd.StartInfo.Arguments);
                Console.WriteLine("Process Id {0}", cmd.Id);
                if (Started != null)
                    Started(this, null);
            }
            return retval;
        }

        public void KillProcess()
        {
            if (IsRunning)
            {
                cmd.Kill();
            }
        }

        public void SetupProcess(string program, string args)
        {
            cmd = new Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = program;
            cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
            cmd.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            //cmd.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
            cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmd.Exited += new EventHandler(cmd_Exited);
        }

        private void cmd_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pIsRunning = false;
            if (Exited != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("thread {0} received exit signal", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Console.WriteLine("Process {0} exited. notfying queue...", ((Process)sender).Id);
                Exited(this, null); // signal the queue to run the next process
            }
        }

    }

// usage
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessEx s = new ProcessEx();
            s.SetupProcess(@"C:\MyP\MBN\Dev\Test\Hello\bin\Debug\Hello.exe", "process 0");
            ProcessExQueue q = new ProcessExQueue();
            q.Add(s);
            s = new ProcessEx();
            s.SetupProcess(@"C:\MyP\MBN\Dev\Test\Hello\bin\Debug\Hello.exe", "process 1");
            q.Add(s);

            s = new ProcessEx();
            s.SetupProcess(@"C:\MyP\MBN\Dev\Test\Hello\bin\Debug\Hello.exe", "process 2");
            q.Add(s);

            q.Done = () => Console.WriteLine("Done!");

            q.StartFirstProcesses();
            /*
            Thread t = new Thread(q.StartFirstProcesses);
            t.Start();
            */
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
// sample process
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Count() > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Console.WriteLine("exiting... press any key");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be looking for the Thread.Join method?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Which allows your parent thread to wait on a child thread.

Comment: I am talking about different processes here!  so your suggestion is not applicable.

Comment: I realized that after you posted the code, but by that time already down voted. Oh well..my fault for not using comments to get clarification.

Answer (score -1):

I like the Timer solution suggested by GrawCube.  I implemented this without the use of a timer,  but the timer solution may be cleaner.  Credit also goes to Deadly-Bagel for posting the original code which I modified to add delay and cpu threshold.  Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessEx s = new ProcessEx();
        s.SetupProcess(@"C:\MyP\MBN\Dev\Test\Hello\bin\Debug\Hello.exe", "process 0");
        ProcessExQueue q = new ProcessExQueue();
        q.Add(s);
        s = new ProcessEx();
        s.SetupProcess(@"C:\MyP\MBN\Dev\Test\Hello\bin\Debug\Hello.exe", "process 1");
        q.Add(s);

        s = new ProcessEx();
        s.SetupProcess(@"C:\MyP\MBN\Dev\Test\Hello\bin\Debug\Hello.exe", "process 2");
        q.Add(s);

        Thread t = new Thread(q.StartFirstProcesses);
        t.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
}

class ProcessExQueue
{
    private List<ProcessEx> Servers = new List<ProcessEx>();
    public int MaxConcurrent { get; set; }
    public int Delay { get; set; }
    byte _running = 0;

    public ProcessExQueue()
    {
        MaxConcurrent = 4;
        Delay = 60000;
    }

    public void Add(ProcessEx Server)
    {
        Servers.Add(Server);
        Server.Exited += cmd_Exited;
        Server.Started += cmd_Started;
    }

    private bool RunNextProcess()
    {
        bool retval = false;
        if (Servers.Count > 0)
        {
            ProcessEx ToRun = Servers[0];
            Servers.Remove(ToRun);
            retval = ToRun.StartProcess();
            if (retval)
                lock (this)
                {
                    _running++;
                }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Thread Id {0} will sleep...", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(Delay);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread Id {0} woke up", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return retval;
    }

    public void StartFirstProcesses()
    {
        while (Servers.Count > 0 && _running <= MaxConcurrent)
        {
            RunNextProcess();
        }
    }

    private void cmd_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            _running--;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Queue: process exited {0}.", ((ProcessEx)sender).GetPID());
       if(Servers.Count > 0 && _running <= MaxConcurrent)
        {
            RunNextProcess();
        }
    }

    private void cmd_Started(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Queue: process started {0}", ((ProcessEx)sender).GetPID());
    }
}

class ProcessEx
{
    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get
        {
            return pIsRunning;
        }
    }

    private bool pIsRunning = false;

    public delegate void OutputEventHandler(ProcessEx sender, string Output, bool IsError);

    public delegate void StatusEventHandler(ProcessEx sender, EventArgs e);


    public event StatusEventHandler Started;
    public event StatusEventHandler Exited;

    private Process cmd;

    public int GetPID()
    {
        return cmd.Id;
    }

    public bool StartProcess()
    {
        bool retval = false;
        if (cmd.Start())
        {
            pIsRunning = true;
            retval = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Running  {0} {1}", cmd.StartInfo.FileName, cmd.StartInfo.Arguments);
            Console.WriteLine("Process Id {0}", cmd.Id);
            if (Started != null)
                Started(this, null);
        }
        return retval;
    }

    public void KillProcess()
    {
        if (IsRunning)
        {
            cmd.Kill();
        }
    }

    public void SetupProcess(string program, string args)
    {
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx
        cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = program;
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
        cmd.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        //cmd.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.Exited += new EventHandler(cmd_Exited);
    }

    private void cmd_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pIsRunning = false;
        if (Exited != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("thread {0} received exit signal", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Console.WriteLine("Process {0} exited. notfying queue...", ((Process)sender).Id);
            Exited(this, null); // signal the queue to run the next process
        }
    }

}
```

}